# Is there a way to combine these rows? html scraping

Tags: html, r, bind, screen-scraping

Scraping webpages for an assignment and ran into a problem. I scraped 12 web pages into a document with the following syntax:

```html
for(i in seq_along(qb_url))
{
  qb_data <- 
    GET(qb_url[i])$content %>% 
    rawToChar() %>% 
    htmlParse() %>% 
    readHTMLTable(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
    extract2(1) %>% 
    bind_rows(qb_data)
}
```

This output a data frame scraping 12 pages of nfl football stats. Each page was one stat... for example, a table for all time TD leaders. Then a table for all time interception leaders. QB rating leaders. Etc. So I ended up with a data frame that has a bunch of different QBs and repeats them all, instead of putting each QB into one row... For example, Drew Brees shows up on all of the records. So the data looks like this (except with a bunch of other QBs thrown into the mix as well, I filtered for Drew Brees only)

[qb stats table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlpdV.png)

Sorry for the formatting on the table here. But basically, is there a way to collapse this so I can have ONE line for each QB, instead of a bunch of NA's with one stat on each line?? I'm going to throw out the first column and the rank column and the link column... just haven't got that far yet.

I'm thinking it has to do with the bind_rows part of my syntax...

Thankful for any help you all have!

Comment: qb_url is not provided, in order to generate the scrap.

Comment: sorry, it's provided in my previous code. I can provide it if you need it...

Comment: This might help you better see what's going on.

Comment: ```url <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/leaders/"```  ```qb_url <- ```
  ```paste(```
    ```url,```
    ```qb_ids```,
    ```sep = ""```
```)```  

```qb_data <- data.frame()```

Comment: sorry I'm REALLY struggling with the formatting... but qb_url <- should be a separate line and so should qb_data <-

Comment: @MarcioRodrigues so the qb_url is provided :) I have the table, the pages were scraped. It's the output I don't have quite right... Per the image link.

Comment: Please don't add clarification/code in comments. Edit your post and include `url`, `qb_url` and also `qb_ids`.

Comment: Can't scrap your example without qb_ids

Answer (score 0):

Here's some dummy data

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  player = rep(c("Alice", "Bob", "Carol"), each = 3),
  x = rep(c(1, NA, NA), times  = 3),
  y = rep(c(NA, 1, NA), times  = 3),
  z = rep(c(NA, NA, 1), times  = 3)
)
df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   player     x     y     z
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Alice      1    NA    NA
#> 2 Alice     NA     1    NA
#> 3 Alice     NA    NA     1
#> 4 Bob        1    NA    NA
#> 5 Bob       NA     1    NA
#> 6 Bob       NA    NA     1
#> 7 Carol      1    NA    NA
#> 8 Carol     NA     1    NA
#> 9 Carol     NA    NA     1
```

Use `group_by` and `summarise` to remove the `NA` values.

```
df %>%
  group_by(player) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~first(na.omit(.))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   player     x     y     z
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Alice      1     1     1
#> 2 Bob        1     1     1
#> 3 Carol      1     1     1
```